# SharePoint Online Managed Properties Documentation

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, groups, query, properties

I'm trying to figure out how to limit a SharePoint Online people search to only people that are part of a certain Office365 security group and was going to attempt to do that by querying managed properties.

However, I can't seem to figure out what a lot of these properties return exactly to figure out how to write the query and was hoping maybe there'd be some sort of documentation but I can't find anything (specifically the Member_Groups property and the crawled property, `People:SPS-MemberOf`, so that I can map a managed property to it if it's what I'm looking for).

Does anyone know where I might be able to find documentation on the specific properties and what information they hold?

Thank you! Also would love other other recommendations (if anyone has any) for how I might be able to go about performing the above task but this is the direction I'm going at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crawled property **People:SPS-MemberOf** represents **SPS-MemberOf** user property in user profile, which imports from windows server Active Directory, this doesn't applied to Azure AD.

[image]

In addition, modern search crawl the people related information from user profile, rather than crawl the group.

If you want to limit people search to only people that are part of a certain Office365 security group, it's recommended to set unified property in this group such as Department, then change the query in people result source to search only the department equals one value.

References:

https://www.hr365.us/docs/active-directory-attribute-and-sharepoint-online-user-profile-mapping/

https://blog.westmorr.com/2018/09/10/office-365-and-sharepoint-company-directory-and-people-finder-with-search-and-user-profiles/

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll go ahead and explore these options then for what I want to do :) Appreciate it!